# Delete patches that have a specific color

Tags: netlogo

How can I delete patches that have a specific color ("clear-patches" deletes all patches? For example, from this code, I would like to delete all blue patches and keep only yellow patches.

```
to test
clear-all
ask patches [ set pcolor yellow]
repeat 20 [
 ask one-of patches with [pcolor = yellow] [ set pcolor blue]
]
end
```

Thank you very much for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly sure what you what "deleting" a patch to mean. Unlike turtles and links, patches cannot be killed.

If by "delete a patch" you mean "reset all of the patch's variables to their defaults", there isn't any command in NetLogo that does that to only some patches, instead of all them.

If you just want to clear certain variables in certain patches, you have to name those variables explicitly, for example:

```
ask patches with [pcolor = blue] [
  set pcolor black
  set plabel ""
  ...
]
```